# (anonymous function) when passing data using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

i'm a new user to LARVEL, when i develop im encountering this problem, hope someone can help me

What i use to develop =>
PHP Laravel 5.2

What error i'm encountering =>
POST 500 internal server error point to =>
(anonymous function)

This is my ajaxcreate.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
            placeholder="Enter some name" required>
        <p class="error text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="add">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> ADD
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <table class="table table-borderless" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Details</th>
                <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($data as $item)
        <tr class="item{{$item->id}}">
            <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->details}}</td>
            <td><button class="edit-modal btn btn-info" data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-name="{{$item->name}}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                </button>
                <button class="delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-name="{{$item->name}}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>


<script>
$("#add").click(function() {

    $.ajax({    // this is where my console said the anonymous function
        type: 'post',
        url: 'addItem',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if ((data.errors)) {
                $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
            } else {
                $('.error').remove();
                $('#table').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
            }
        },
    });
    $('#name').val('');
});
</script>
@endsection
```

this is my AjaxController.php

```
public function addItem(Request $request) 
    {

        $data = new Product ();
        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->details = $request->name;
        $data->save ();
    }
```

this is my routes.php

```
Route::post('/addItem','AjaxController@addItem');

Route::get('/readItem','AjaxController@readItems');
```

Comment: You can always look inside your `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see a proper stack trace of your error. My initial thought is that `$data = new Product ();` should not have the `()`; it should just be `$data = new Product;`. The rest of it looks fine, as long as the route it is posting to is valid. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yeah it helps, and the error point to this //local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\wamp64\www\testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:67// @James do you know what its mean? THX!

Comment: The error you are getting is a token mismatch exception, which means the CSRF token you are passing with your request is not valid. Looking at your code above I don't see a `_token` field. Make sure you have this on the page for your CSRF token to be retrieved.

Comment: Thx @James for pointing out the problem, i already solved it by changing this '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val() to '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mismatch token

so all i have to do is change

```
data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val()
      },
```

to

```
data: {
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val()
      }
```